# Why am I getting this output? (Shopping Cart Program)

Tags: python

Current Code Snippet:

```
for x in range(len(cart)+1):
    if book[int(bookInput)- 1][1] in cart:
        cart[x][0]+=1
    else:
        cart.append([1,book[int(bookInput)- 1][0],book[int(bookInput)- 1][1]])
```

Current Output:

```
[[1, 'The Lincoln Highway', 30.0], [1, 'The Lincoln Highway', 30.0], [1, 'The Lincoln Highway', 30.0]]
[[1, 'The Lincoln Highway', 30.0], [1, 'The Lincoln Highway', 30.0], [1, 'The Lincoln Highway', 30.0]]
[[1, 'The Lincoln Highway', 30.0], [1, 'The Lincoln Highway', 30.0], [1, 'The Lincoln Highway', 30.0]]
```

Output desired:

```
    [[2, 'The Lincoln Highway', 30.0]]
```

I'm creating a counter for each item to prevent duplicates from being added to the shopping cart list. Been banging my head against my keyboard for days and I can't figure this out! It doesn't recognize that the item is already in the cart.

Comment: Why are you adding 1 to `len(cart)`? That will make `x` go outside the range of indexes on the last iteration.

Comment: How are you actually outputting anything when you don't have any print statements?

Comment: What is in `cart`? If you're trying to eliminate duplicates, why not put them into a set/mutliset?

Comment: What's the value of `book[int(bookInput)- 1][1]` If that's a book title, the `in cart` test won't be true, since the elements of `cart` are lists, not strings.

Comment: The items aren't initially added to the cart if I don't have the +1. I suppose when the cart is empty the for loop is for range 0 so it doesn't work?

Comment: Why are you looping at all?

Comment: ewong this is a portion of the code

Comment: I'm looping because that's what my professor showed me to do, then I went home and tested it and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if string 'The Lincoln Highway' is the list of entries (lists) e.g. `[1, 'The Lincoln Highway', 30.0]` so that's why your check fails

```py
added = False # so we know whether to add a new entry at the end
for i in cart:
    if book[int(bookInput)- 1][1] == i[1]: 
        i[0] += 1
        added = True
        break
if not added:
    cart.append([1,book[int(bookInput)- 1][0],book[int(bookInput)- 1][1]])
```

Even better, would be to implement cart as set/dict since you will be checking membership quite often e.g.

```py
cart = { "book" : (quantity, price)}
if book in cart: 
    q, p = cart[book]
    cart[book] = (q+1, p)
```

or similar.

Comment: This won't work if the cart is empty.

Comment: This looks like it makes sense but now I try to append and it won't append

Comment: Python has `else:` on its loops so you don't need the `added` variable.

Comment: Your first response is pretty much identical to my professor's example but when I print cart even after running the program it's still empty!

Comment: @DavidAhlstrom I just ran it on my machine it works, can you show us the input/expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The `else:` shouldn't be on the `if` statement. That will cause you to add a new item to the cart for every existing item that doesn't match the current book.

Use the `else:` clause of the `for` loop. This executes if the loop runs to completion. Then inside the loop, use `break` to stop early if you find the matching book.

```
title = book[int(bookInput)-1][0]
for item in cart:
    if item[1] == title:
        item[0] += 1
        break
else:
    cart.append([1, title, book[int(bookInput)-1][1]
```